# Subtract 14 days from system date

Tags: sql, oracle, sap-data-services

I am using the following code to give me the system date in `BODS`, `to_char(sysdate(),'YYYYMMDDHHMISS')`, I have the system date returning correctly, but am unable to subtract days.

`FAGLFLEXA.TIMESTAMP >= "MISSING CODE HERE"`  and `FAGLFLEXA.TIMESTAMP <= to_char(sysdate(),'YYYYMMDDHHMISS')`

Comment: for DATE, subtracting 1, goes back 1 day.

Comment: @thatjeffsmith how is that written out though, I have tried both inside the date format and outside but am getting an error

Comment: try to_char(sysdate - 7,'yyyymmddhhmiss').  I don't think you want () after your sysdate

Comment: Why is this tagged `JavaScript`?

Comment: not sure why you are to_char(sysdate)...just do SYSDATE - 7 to reference this this moment right now, 7 days ago

Answer (score 2):

You can subtract days from a date by subtracting a whole number. Also, for some reason you are using `sysdate()` which is not proper Oracle format.

```
to_char(sysdate-14,'YYYYMMDDHHMISS')
```